# AngularDart: Child does not fit to width parent

Tags: angular-dart

I would like to fit child `<material-expansionpanel>` that is into a AngularDart component invoked into `<material-tab>` to reach parent´s width.

I used [flex] directive, but did not work. How could I to do this work?

[image]

See the picture. The `<material-expansionpanel>` does not expand to right side.

Code:

```
<!-- parent -->
    <material-tab-panel>
    <material-tab [flex] label="Formação do Preço">

            <precomi-formacaopreco></precomi-formacaopreco>

    </material-tab>

<!-- child <precomi-formacaopreco> -->
<div>
    <material-expansionpanel name="Atividade Principal" flex [showSaveCancel]="false">
      <material-radio-group flex>
        <material-radio [checked]="true">Comércio</material-radio>
        <material-radio>Indústria</material-radio>
        <material-radio>Serviços</material-radio>
      </material-radio-group>
    </material-expansionpanel>
...
</div
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not think `[flex]` does anything in particular here. If you don't constraint width then expansion panel should take whole horizontal space. If that doesn't happen you can try filing an issue to angular_components with runnable reproduction instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be that your `<div>` the `<material-expansionpanel>` does not expand to the width of page. Can you try setting the width of the `<div>` to 100%?

Comment: I tried `div { width: 100%; }`, but it didn´t work. If I set with value like `width: 1200px` on parent then the child expands normaly to reach this length. But I don´t want to use value fixed.

Comment: Can you try adding position: relative to the div in addition to width: 100%?